# HTTPS Not working on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

I'm having a weird issue on my Macbook Pro (OSX 10.7 Lion) where ANY site on ANY browser doesn't function if it is using HTTPS. For example, http://google.com will appear, but **https**://google.com will say 'Not Available'. It doesn't matter what browser I'm using (I've used Safari, Chrome and Firefox). I've encountered the issue on many different wifi networks.

I've tried adding a new 'Location' in my Network settings which didn't work. I've disabled the Mac Firewall, reset Wifi, disabled all Proxy checkboxes in the Wifi Settings. It's very strange and freaking me out a bit. Any help?

Comment: Is your time/date set correctly?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same prolem (on OS 10.6)

Answer (score 2):

Had this recently when my time and date was reset. Try setting them again.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for any other machine using the same connection? If not, could be the MTU on your router - it's very common to see problems with sites using https if the MTU is too high (above 1440 for an ADSL connection, for example).